# Media query width removes div styling

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries

At the bottom of the short stylesheet below you will see that I have a media query (landscape iPad) that should change the width of the debugger div. When testing on the iPad in landscape mode it completely removes all styling for the debugger div. If I remove the width property and change it to say, `color: red` that will work just fine. Although when attempting to change the width, it just removes all styling.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Conv_PoetsenOne-Regular', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
}

#debugger {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
  background: #0e98f5; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0e98f5 0%, #0794ea 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#0e98f5), color-stop(100%,#0794ea)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0e98f5 0%,#0794ea 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0e98f5 0%,#0794ea 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0e98f5 0%,#0794ea 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #0e98f5 0%,#0794ea 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0e98f5', endColorstr='#0794ea',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  color: white;
  opacity: .85;
  z-index: 10;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}

#debugger-content {
    padding: 10px 25px;
}

#status {
    text-align: center;
  background: #0e98f5; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0e98f5 0%, #0794ea 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#0e98f5), color-stop(100%,#0794ea)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0e98f5 0%,#0794ea 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0e98f5 0%,#0794ea 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0e98f5 0%,#0794ea 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #0e98f5 0%,#0794ea 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0e98f5', endColorstr='#0794ea',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}

#status-content {
    padding-top: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { 
    #debugger {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: What iPad are you using, the pixel-ratio you have specified will use ipad2 and lower

Comment: @Vector I'm using the iPad 1. Still can't get my head around this.. very weird.